# Magento Multiple Dynamic Custom Routes For Single Store

Tags: magento, routes, magento2, router, magento2.2

I want to load my magento store on 
www.example.com/var1/var2
Instead of www.example.com and i want my products url like www.example.com/var1/var2/product-url
Var1 & var2 can be dynamic variables.
Help me to rewrite my urls in maganeto 2.2.6

What I have tried is developing a custom module but now all I have to do is to load all magento modules in my custom module. It seems am working with totally custom in magento which is not a good practice. By this way I have to reinitialize my all magento modules into my custom module. By this way magento is useless for me by using this approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Request Routing in this case by do the following steps:

1. create di.xml under YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml with this content:

`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_router" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class"
                          xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Controller\Router
                    </item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>`

2. Create Router class that implement RouterInterface as below:

   class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
   {
       private $actionFactory;

   ```
   /**
    * Router constructor.
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
    */

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory)
   {
       $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
   }

   public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
   {
       $info = $request->getPathInfo();
       if (preg_match("%^/(var1/var2)(.*?)$%", $info, $m)) {
           $request->setPathInfo(str_replace('var1/var2', '', $info));
           return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
               ['request' => $request]);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Run this command:

   php bin/magento s:up

Enter your url like www.example.com/var1/var2 and see the result

Comment: I have tried this and its working already. But its loading home page only. I want that all my urls like my product hrefs and my cart page link should be converted into www.example.com/var1/var2/my-cart or  www.example.com/var1/var2/my-product

Comment: I don't want to change base_url because var1 and var2 are dynamic and I do not want to update the database again and again for every single user with different var1/var2

Comment: var1/var2 are basically var1 is type and var2 is vendor name so both can be change again and again